# Profiling mysql on two different servers

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two mysql databases that are identical. One is running locally and one is running on a production server. The one that runs locally is consistently 3x faster on all queries, even though the production server is larger more memory and better CPU than my local machine.

I did `SHOW PROFILES` and it doesn't show anything definitive, most of the items are the same, though sometimes the local machine is ~10-20% better. How would I determine where this difference is coming from? Perhaps it has to do with networking performance, but I'm not sure how I would profile that with mysql queries.

What would you suggest as to how to figure this out and improve the production db performance?

Comment: database size? your local is likely to have much fewer records (if it's just a dev environment). do you have the same indexes on both?

Comment: Are many people using the production database at the same time?

Comment: @TarynEast -- yes the database contents are identical.

Comment: is the prod server *actually* a real computer, or a shared slice on a shared server pretending to be a real server with better CPU/RAM etc :) (just thinking of all the possibilities)

Comment: @TarynEast it's an RDS database server.

Comment: hmmm... plausibly it's network lag for all db IO - ie your prod server is not the same machine as the database server, whereas on your local machine - likely you're running the server and DB server on the same machine? (note: still totally guessing here). Doesn't seem like this would account for a 3X difference though...

Comment: What tells you "3x"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Profile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) the query to see where the time is being spent. A long "sending data" stage will show if it's network latency.

Always use [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) when measuring query time.

Comment: How do I set `SQL_NO_CACHE` ? Is it: `set sql_no_cache=1` ? or do I need to do it somewhere else?

Comment: Just use it after SELECT like `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table1`.